# How to use query through Realm in Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

My code I have problem doing Query in Realm I am using Realm in Xcode

```
extension CategoryViewController: UISearchBarDelegate{
  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    realmCategories = realmCategories?.filter("title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!).sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: true)
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text?.count == 0{
      loadCategory()
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okey your query is wrong you should use apostrophe for string types. In your code the query must be like this:

```
    realmCategories = realmCategories?.filter("title CONTAINS[cd] '%@'", searchBar.text!).sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSPredicate thats what the function ".filter" expect

NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)

```
Returns a Results containing all objects matching the given predicate in the collection.
func filter(_ predicate: NSPredicate) -> Results<Object>
```